# In Vite Res.Cookie is Not Working. Respons is comming perfectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vite, vite-reactjs

**In Vite res.cookie is not set the cookie**

**I don't know why.**

[in this code I am send cookie in res but it is not set in cooke with Vite react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDyi8.png)

[This is fetching the login URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhhtZ.png)
[console.log of line no. 31 in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTfOH.png)
[In network res showing Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0MmVkNjk2MTkwODUxZWFjZjRjZWNmNCIsImlhdCI6MTY4MTU5NzAyNSwiZXhwIjoxNjgyMDI5MDI1fQ.JAA_1TDtrBry3MhuAXGi0DrtmVQ5uAPMoaIavOgsPcc; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 15 Apr 2023 22:17:35 GMT; HttpOnly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjE9v.png)

but this cookie is not showing in application cookie
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqsNk.png)

res is coming perfectly

**Code of send cookie with token**

```
`const sendToken = async (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = await user.getJwtToken();
  const option = {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(
      new Date(Date.now() + 30000)
    ),
  };

  console.log(
    process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE,
    option,
  );

  return res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, option).json({
    success: true,
    user,
    token,
  });
};`
```

export default sendToken;

```
**Code of fetch login on vite React**

`export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "loginUser",
  async (args, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        header: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      };
      let url = `${import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/dashboard_login`;

      const user = await axios.post(url, args, config);
      
      console.log(user);
      return await user.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return await err.response.data;
    }
  }
);`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.